# Beautifulsoup 4 can't find css and html tag

Tags: html, beautifulsoup

Beautifulsoup cannot find the tag on the page using the find method.

```
url = 'https://qgold.com/pl/Jewelry-Rings-2%C2%B7Stone-Rings'
request = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(request.text, "html.parser")
tovar = soup.find_all("div", class\_="row product-list")
Returns an empty list
```

HTML code example

```
\<div \_ngcontent-itb-c83="" class="row product-list"\>\<div \_ngcontent-itb-c83="" class="col-lg-3 col-md-4
```

I tried:

```
`tovar = soup.css.select("row product-list")
tovar = soup.find("row product-list")
tovar = soup.find_all("row product-list")
tovar = soup.find_all(class\_=re.compile("row product-list"))
tovar = soup.find_all(string=re.compile("ro`your text`w product-list"))
tovar = soup.find_all(string="row product-list")`
```

Comment: this site uses javascript to load the page, so you won't be able to get it with bs4, try Selenium

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do the scraping only with BeautifulSoup, but it didn't work, so I resorted to Selenium, and all ok, I provide you the code I used. You must download and install the chrome driver for it to work.

```html
import csv
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://qgold.com/pl/Jewelry-Rings-2·Stone-Rings"
all_data = []

# Selenium Configuration
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  # Running in headless mode
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

# Access to page
driver.get(url)

# Wait for products to load
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div > p.description > span")))

# Get the HTML content of the page
html = driver.page_source
driver.quit()  # Close the browser before parsing with BeautifulSoup

# Extracting the necessary data using BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
products = soup.select('div > p.description > span')
prices = soup.select('div > p.sku-price > span')
stocks = soup.select('div > p.stock-item.stock-item-out.available-msg.ng-star-inserted > span')

for title, price, stock in zip(products, prices, stocks):
    title_text = title.get_text(strip=True) if title else ""
    price_text = price.get_text(strip=True) if price else ""
    stock_text = stock.get_text(strip=True) if review else ""
    all_data.append([title_text, price_text, stock_text])

# Write data to a CSV file
with open("gold.csv", "w", newline="", encoding="utf-8") as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow(['Product', 'Price', 'Stock'])
    writer.writerows(all_data)
```